# Python wifi install issue

Tags: python, wifi

Struggling to understand this, so time to call in the cavalry!

Raspberry pi running Raspbian & Python 2.7

Trying to connect to wifi with WiPi dongle through Python.
Done sudo pip install wifi which reports as successful.

In Python I `import wifi` which is OK, but when I try `from wifi import Cell, Scheme` I get the following :-

```
ImportError: cannot import name Cell
```

I've been trying to resolve this for 2 days without success, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have a file in your local directory called "wifi.py"? If so, rename it.

Comment: Daniel, Yes I did have a file named wifi which I have now renamed but without resolve.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to overcome this issue, by renaming my python file a name without wifi in the name. It seems to cause a conflict because of the name wifi

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, rename any folders/files you're using that have the word "wifi" in them. I had my files in a directory named "Wifi", this was causing an issue.